# How to completely block the screen behind ngx boostrap modal so that the buttons in the background don't work even using keyboard enter?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I have this ngx bootstrap modal and it works perfectly:

```
<div bsModal #myModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        ...
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click somewhere on the background it doesn't close and I also can't click on the buttons in the background using my mouse. **However**, when I use the **tab key on my keyboard**, I can navigate through my buttons in the background and eventually click on a button.
I am looking for a way to stop this behavior, so that the user cannot click the keys using keyboard either. How can I do it?

Comment: To avoid tabing in yours elements you can set `tabindex="-1"`

Comment: It could be a solution, but I only want the elements to be disabled when the modal opens.